# insert data from textbox with multiple lines contents into sql table

Tags: asp.net

i have put the following code in .aspx

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtyourwords" runat="server" Rows="1" TextMode="MultiLine">
</asp:TextBox>


SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert INTO planning_t (date,course,planning) values("+Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString()+","+DropDownList2.SelectedIt‌​‌​em.Text+","+txtyourwords.Text.ToString()+" )", con);
```

now i want to insert the contents of textbox--(txtyourwords) into a table...
what will be code in C# for .cs file.
and
datatype for this column is varchar(MAX).

Comment: You havent posted the code.

Comment: error is:
Error getting data. Incorrect syntax near 'Engineering'.
'Engineering' is dropdownlist.selecteditem.text

Comment: {SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert INTO planning_t (date,course,planning) values("+Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString()+","+DropDownList2.SelectedIt‌​em.Text+","+txtyourwords.Text.ToString()+" )", con);}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert INTO planning_t (date,course,planning) values('"+Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString()+"','"+DropDownList2.SelectedIt‌​em.Text+"','"+txtyourwords.Text.ToString()+"' )", con);
```